# MkMapView : Get lattitude and longitude when user moves the map

Tags: objective-c

i'am new to iphone MapView,when user moves the Map i need to get latitude and longitude of the visible region in iphone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the coordinates of the point at the center of the map with the properties of the MKMapView :
`centerCoordinate.latitude` and `centerCoordinate.longitude`.

**For example :**

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(
              map.centerCoordinate.latitude, map.centerCoordinate.longitude);
```

That's theses latitude and longitude you mean by "*i need latitude and longitude when user moves map*" ?

Hope this helps…

Comment: How can we find out user has moving a map.

Comment: I never tried that, but regards to the [Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html), `- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated` seems to be the good delegate method.

Answer (score 1):

Use the .region property of your MKMapView.

```
MKMapView *myMapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:...];

MKCoordinateRegion region = myMapView.region;

// Center of the screen as lat/long
// region.center.latitude
// region.center.longitude

// width and height of viewing area as lat/long
// region.span.latitudeDelta
// region.span.longitudeDelta
```

Max

Comment: i need latitude and longitude when user moves map with finger.and every time i will send this lat and longitude to find the restaurants.

Comment: Hi mxweas i have one doubt

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your `Appdelegate.h`

```
CLLocationManager *locationManager;
```

and then add these lines in your `Appdelegate.m (didFinishLaunchingWithOptions)`

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
[locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

this will call a method when you move with device,

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    CLLocation *currentLocation = [locations lastObject];

    NSString *latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    NSString *longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];

    NSMutableArray *temp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
    [temp addObject:latitude];
    [temp addObject:longitude];

    NSUserDefaults *def = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [def setObject:temp forKey:@"CLocation"];

    [temp release];
}
```

Use from this.

Comment: its fine but i need latitude and longitude when user moves map with finger.